# Refreshing the table in child component based on filtering data in the parent component

Tags: angular

I have a table in child component that I am populating by passing the object from the parent component. The object that I am passing is called FundClasses

I am trying to filter some values in the parent component based on checkbox selection on the child component. The method in the parent component where I am filtering based on the child component checkbox selection is called getInvestedDetails.

I can see the object gets updated but the table is not refreshed. How do i refresh the table. When I call the init method using viewchild, the page rendered is blank.

Child component html

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" checked="checked" (click)="isInvestedSelected($event)" />
    <label for="chkInvested">Invested</label>

</div>


<div class="card scrollClass">
    <div class="card-header panel-heading">
        <span class="left-label" style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">Fund Classes</span>
        <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:10px; display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle">
            <!-- <label style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle" class="btn btn-default pull-right"> <i
                    data-bind="visible: true" class="fa fa-plus-square"></i><input type="checkbox" class="hidden" /> Add
                Class</label> -->
            <button style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle" class="btn btn-default pull-right" (click)="openFundClassModal()"> <i
                data-bind="visible: true" class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Add Class</button>    
        </div>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="FundClasses && FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel">

        <table class="fundClassesTable table-striped">

            <tr>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Fund Name</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Accounting Class Name</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Class ID</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Legal Fund Class</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Inception Date</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Invested Amount</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Vehicle Type</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Closure Status</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Is Side Pocket?</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Is Thematic?</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Cogency Class?</th>
                <th class="tableItem"></th>
            </tr>

            <ng-container *ngFor="let fundClass of FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel">
                <tr *ngFor="let f of fundClass['FundClassDetailsViewModel'] | keyvalue">
                    <td class="tableItem">{{ f.value.FundName}}</td>
                    <td class="tableItem">{{ f.value.Description}}</td>
                    <td class="tableItem">{{f.value.Id}}</td>
                    <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="f.value.LegalFundClassId"
                            class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="fundClass.PrimaryLegalFundClasses"
                            [filterable]="false" textField="Description" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                        </kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.LegalFundClassName}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <kendo-datepicker style="width:100%" [format]="'dd-MM-yyyy'" 
                            [(ngModel)]="f.value.InceptionDate"
                            class="form-control  form-control-sm">
                        </kendo-datepicker>
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.InceptionDate | date:"'dd-MM-yyyy"}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.value.InvestedAmount"
                            style="width: 284px; height: 29.5px;" />
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.InvestedAmount | number : '.2-2'}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="f.value.VehicleTypeId"
                            class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="FundClasses.VehicleTypes" [filterable]="false"
                            textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id"></kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.VehicleTypeName}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="f.value.ClosureStatusId"
                            class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="FundClasses.ClosureStatuses"
                            [filterable]="false" textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                        </kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.ClosureStatusName}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{f.value.IsSidePocket}}" id="chkSidePocket"  [(ngModel)]="f.value.IsSidePocket"
                            style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />
                        <label for="chk">Yes</label>

                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.IsSidePocket == true ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{f.value.IsThematic}}" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;"   [(ngModel)]="f.value.IsThematic" />
                        <label for="chkThematic">Yes</label>
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.IsThematic == true ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="f.value.CogencyClassId"
                            class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="fundClass.CogencyClasses" [filterable]="false"
                            textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id"></kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.CogencyClassId}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="tableItem">

                        <button *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1 col-sm-4"
                            (click)="buttonClicked(f.value.Id)">Edit</button>
                        <button *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1 col-sm-3"
                            (click)="Update(f.value.Id)">Save</button>
                        <button *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1  col-sm-3"
                            (click)="Delete(f.value.Id)">Delete</button>
                        <button *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1  col-sm-3"
                            (click)="buttonClicked(f.value.Id)">Cancel</button>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-container>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Child component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { TermsService } from '../../services/terms.service';
import { NotifyService } from '../../utilities/notify.service';
import { AddFundClassComponent } from './addFundClass.component';


@Component({
    selector: 'mgr-fund-classes',
    templateUrl: './fundClasses.component.html'
})


export class FundClassesComponent implements OnInit {

    private _fundClasses: any;
    FundClass: any;
    public fundClassKeys = [];
    public EditMode: any = {};
    public fundClassWindowOpened: boolean;
    @Output() termDetailsEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
    @ViewChild(AddFundClassComponent)
    addFundClassComponent: AddFundClassComponent;

    public get FundClasses(): any {
        return this._fundClasses;
    }
    @Input()
    public set FundClasses(value: any) {
        this._fundClasses = value;
    }

    constructor(private termsService: TermsService, private notify: NotifyService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.init();
    }

    buttonClicked(id) {
        this.EditMode[id] = !this.EditMode[id];
    }

    Update(id) {
        this.FundClass = this.FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel
            .reduce((prev, next) => prev.concat(next.FundClassDetailsViewModel), [])
            .find(obj => obj.Id === id);

        this.termsService.updateFundClasses(this.FundClass).then((result) => {
            if (result) {
                this.notify.success('Fund Class Details Successfully Updated');
                this.EditMode = !this.EditMode;
                this.termDetailsEvent.next('getTermsDetails');
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            this.notify.error('An Error Has Occured While Updating Fund Class Details');
        });
    }

    Delete(id) {

        this.termsService.deleteFundClasses(id).then((result) => {
            if (result) {
                this.notify.success('Fund Class Successfully Deleted');
                this.EditMode = !this.EditMode;
                this.termDetailsEvent.next('getTermsDetails');
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            this.notify.error('An Error Has Occured While Updating Fund Class Details');
        });
    }

    openFundClassModal() {
        if (this.addFundClassComponent != null) {
            this.fundClassWindowOpened = true;
        }
    }

    dismissFundClassModal() {
        this.fundClassWindowOpened = false;
    }

    isInvestedSelected(s) {
        this.termDetailsEvent.emit(s.target.checked);
    }


    init() {

    }
}
```

Parent component

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { TermsService } from '../services/terms.service';
import { FundClassesComponent } from './fundClasses/fundClasses.component';


@Component({
selector : 'mgr-terms',
templateUrl : 'terms.component.html'
})


export class TermsComponent implements OnInit {

    private Error: string;
    public TermDetails: any;
    private _ManagerStrategyId: number;
    public get ManagerStrategyId(): number {
        return this._ManagerStrategyId;
    }

    @ViewChild(FundClassesComponent)
    fundClassesComponent: FundClassesComponent;

    @Input()
    public set ManagerStrategyId(value: number) {
        this._ManagerStrategyId = value;
    }
    FundClasses: any;
    constructor(private termsService: TermsService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
            this.init();
    }

    init() {
        this.getTermsDetails();
    }

    public getInvestedDetails(isInvested: boolean) {
         if (isInvested) {
            this.FundClasses = this.TermDetails.FundClassViewModel.FundDetailsViewModel
                                                                  .reduce((prev, next) => prev.concat(next.FundClassDetailsViewModel), [])
                                                                  .filter(obj => obj.InvestedAmount !== null);
           // this.fundClassesComponent.init();
         } else {

         }
    }

    public getTermsDetails() {
        if (this.ManagerStrategyId != null) {
            this.termsService.getTermsDetails(this.ManagerStrategyId).subscribe((data: any) => {
                this.TermDetails = data;
                this.FundClasses = this.TermDetails.FundClassViewModel;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have even tried adding changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush;  in the child component but that doesnt seem to help. The table rendered is blank. I can see the input property in the child component getting correctly initialized with the filtered value

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use OnChanges Angular Lifecycle, to detect changes from parent input at child component. https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges.

```
      ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
         for (let propName in changes) {  
        let change = changes[propName];
        let curVal  = JSON.stringify(change.currentValue);
        let prevVal = JSON.stringify(change.previousValue);
            console.log(curVal);
            console.log(prevVal);
        if(prevVal !== curVal) {
          // trigger your method to setting data
         }
         }
      }
```

Comment: I tried this     ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        // create header using child_id
       console.log(changes);
      }

Comment: The changes.CurrentValue reflects the changes but how do i refresh the table